# How can I solve $y''-2xy'=-2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation ? I search a lot about the answer but i can not find it.
$$\frac12y''-xy'=-1\qquad u=y'$$
$$\frac12u'-xu=-1\qquad u=ue^{x^2}$$
$$y=\int ue^{x^2}\,dx$$
I don't know how can i solve last integral. thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure the differential equation is correct ? This equation does not have a solution over standard function, it rather has a solution over special functions implementing  the generalized hypergeometric function and the error function.

Comment: To find $\int x e^{x^{2}}\, dx$ make the substitution $z=x^{2}$. The solution is in terms of the error function.

Comment: I think in this wiki article you may find anything you need [Linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation), check out the section on First-order equation with variable coefficients using $y^\prime = u$. However, as pointed out by @JoséCarlosSantos, there is no closed solution and you will have to rely on special functions, the error function, in particular, and its integrals.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos my efforts is in the image upload in question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z:=y'$.  Then, you have the differential equation
$$z'(x)-2x\,z(x)=-2\,.$$
Therefore, with $u(x):=\exp(-x^2)\,z(x)$, we have
$$u'(x)=\exp(-x^2)\,\big(z'(x)-2x\,z(x)\big)=-2\,\exp(-x^2)\,.$$
Thus,
$$u(x)=\int_0^x\,\big(-2\,\exp(-t^2)\big)\,\text{d}t+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,a=-\sqrt{\pi}\,\text{erf}(x)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,a$$
for some constant $a$.  (The function $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).)

Therefore,
$$y'(x)=z(x)=\exp(x^2)\,u(x)=-\sqrt{\pi}\,\text{erf}(x)\,\exp(x^2)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,a\,\exp(x^2)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$y(x)=-\sqrt{\pi}\,\int_0^x\,\text{erf}(t)\,\exp(t^2)\,\text{d}t+a\,\text{erfi}(x)+b$$
for some constant $b$.  Here, $\text{erfi}$ is the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).  Note that $y$ can be written in the form of [generalized hypergeometric functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$y(x)=-x^2\,{_2\text{F}_2}\left(1,1;\frac32,2;x^2\right)+a\,\text{erfi}(x)+b\,.$$

Comment: thanks a lot for you help